# Capture Record changes

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, How I can capture the changes in the field Submitted and status for the same Card?

```
ID  Card ID Submitted   STATUS
1   XYZ     1           ACTIVE
1   XYZ     0           DECLINED
1   XYZ     2           ACCEPTED
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean, please elaborate...

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? That is not a technical term (there is no concept of "capturing" in database technology). Do you need to show the changes in a query? Or what else? Also - why do you have an ID column, where all the values are the same? An ID would normally be different on every row.

Comment: @XYZ . . . What results do you want?